# Meteor load static data once for several templates

Tags: performance, meteor, static, publish-subscribe, flow-router

I'm working with meteor and FlowRouter. I have a collection of a country's administrative divisions and the data is about 2000 documents. I read this data in several routes so at the moment I'm subscribing to the same collection every time I visit one of the routes that is using this data.

This is causing a slow performance and a waste of resources. Given that this collection doesn't change, is there any way to load or subscribe to this data once and have it available for the whole app or specific routes?

Maybe save the data in settings.json and have it available as an object would be better?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the subscriptions active between routes. You can do this using this package (written by the same author as FlowRouter so it all works nicely together):

https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager

Alternatively, create a Meteor method to return the data and save it in your Session. In this case it won't be reactive, so it depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks @tarmes, I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

Any subscription you make that's external to the routing will be in global scope, which will then mean that data from that subscription is available everywhere.  All you need to do is set up the subscription say in the root layout file for your site and then that data will be kept in your local minimongo store at all times.

The Todo list collection in the [Todo app example here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe) is an example of this, this is the code from that example:

> ```
> Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
>
> if (Meteor.isServer) {
>   // This code only runs on the server
>   Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
>     return Tasks.find();
>   });
> }
>
> if (Meteor.isClient) {
>   // This code only runs on the client
>   Meteor.subscribe("tasks");
> ```

You can then query that local data as you would normally.

Comment: Thanks for your response @tomRedox